# how to do subqueries in bigquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, google-bigquery, reddit, bigdata

Im trying to play with the reddit data on bigquery and I want to see comments and replies in one row.  I see bigquery supports subqueries, but I am unable to construct the query.  I have to use a subquery to self join the same table because of the structure of the data, specifically i want to join id and parent_id together, but I need to modify id before I can join.  Here is how im trying to do the query:

```
SELECT 
  p.subreddit, 
  p.body AS first_body,
  p.score AS first_score,
  CONCAT('t1_',p.id) AS first_id ,
  c.last_body,
  c.last_score,
  c.last_id 
FROM 
[fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] p,
(
  SELECT 
    body AS last_body,
    score AS last_score,
    CONCAT('t1_',id) AS last_id,
    parent_id,
    author,
    body 
  FROM  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] 
  WHERE body != '[deleted]' 
  AND author != '[deleted]' 
  AND score > 1
)  c
WHERE  p.first_id = c.parent_id  
AND p.score > 1 
AND  p.author != '[deleted]' 
AND p.body != '[deleted]';
```

The error I get is:

```
Field 'c.parent_id' not found in table 'fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01'; did you mean 'parent_id'?
```

Here is where you can run the query:
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01

Im not sure how to fix this.  what is the proper way to join this and get this query to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to do something like below (just guess):

```
SELECT 
  p.subreddit, 
  p.body AS first_body,
  p.score AS first_score,
  CONCAT('t1_',p.id) AS first_id ,
  c.last_body,
  c.last_score,
  c.last_id 
FROM 
[fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] p
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    body AS last_body,
    score AS last_score,
    CONCAT('t1_',id) AS last_id,
    parent_id,
    author,
    body 
  FROM  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] 
  WHERE body != '[deleted]' 
  AND author != '[deleted]' 
  AND score > 1
)  c
ON  p.link_id = c.parent_id  
WHERE p.score > 1 
AND  p.author != '[deleted]' 
AND p.body != '[deleted]'
LIMIT 100
```

See more about [JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#joins)s

Please note, I just transformed your query to proper use JOINs, but logic of query is still for you to polish as you see needed

> Added to address additional info in your comment:

```
SELECT 
  subreddit, 
  first_body,
  first_score,
  first_id ,
  last_body,
  last_score,
  last_id 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    subreddit, 
    body AS first_body,
    score AS first_score,
    CONCAT('t1_',id) AS first_id 
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01]
  WHERE score > 1 
  AND author != '[deleted]' 
  AND body != '[deleted]'
) p
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    body AS last_body,
    score AS last_score,
    CONCAT('t1_',id) AS last_id,
    parent_id,
    author,
    body 
  FROM  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] 
  WHERE body != '[deleted]' 
  AND author != '[deleted]' 
  AND score > 1
)  c
ON  p.first_id = c.parent_id  
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Mikhail, I couldn't use this style specifically because of the join clause. I need to join: on    concat('t1_',p.id) =  c.parent_id   .       the id is missing the "t1_" string in front of it.  bigquery does not allow joins for fields that dont exist in the table.  So I need to modify the query to use subselect I believe.           here is the error I get when I try to use concat: 

Query Failed
Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name. .

Comment: Added to my original answer to reflect your spec for ON clause

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery's SQL dialect, comma means UNION ALL instead of JOIN. You need to write the JOIN explicitly, using the JOIN keyword.

I would also recommend pushing both sides of the join into subqueries to ensure that all filters are applied before the join is executed. (The join is by far the most expensive part of the query, so applying the filters first will ensure that your query runs as fast as possible.)